# Show div based off certain languages

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Spanish translate button on my website that I want to only display when the browser language is set to 'es'

I have the javascript detect the language like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
alert("The language is: " + userLang);
if (userLang = "es") {
    $("#google_translate_element").show();
}
else {
    alert("English");
    $("#google_translate_element").hide();
}
</script>
```

It displays no matter what language my browser is set too. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`=` is used for assignment. For comparison, you need to use `==`. If you want to compare the `type` of the variable as well, then use `===`:

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
alert("The language is: " + userLang);
if (userLang === "es") {
    $("#google_translate_element").show();
}
else {
    alert("English");
    $("#google_translate_element").hide();
}
```

You can read more about expressions and operators from **[MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)**

Answer (score 0):

A more generalized solution:

Some JavaScript:

```
var lang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;

document.documentElement.className = "lang-" + lang;
```

This gives you `<html class="lang-(en|es)">`

Now anywhere you need to do something special based on the language, you can use CSS:

```
#google_translate_element {
    display: none;
}

.lang-es #google_translate_element {
    display: block;
}
```